# Error getting battery Status Service and sending it to wear module

Tags: android, android-service, wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-broadcastreceiver

In my android wear project ...i am trying to get battry status of phone and sending it to Wear device...so i am trying to run an Service which will run in background and register an BroadcastReceiver on action ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED ..onReceive it will send the msg to wear device ..but i having the problem that my broadcastreceiver for Battery status change is not working it only throughs log on first time after that it didnt run on battery status change please help me on this problem....Below is my code for service....

BatteryStatService.java

```
package com.rahul.androidwear;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataApi;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.DataMap;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataMapRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.PutDataRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.wearable.Wearable;

import java.util.Date;

public class BatteryStatService extends Service  implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener  {

    GoogleApiClient googleClient;


    public BatteryStatService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Build a new GoogleApiClient
        googleClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();



        //Register Reciver
        final IntentFilter battChangeFilter = new IntentFilter(
                Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        // register our receiver
        this.registerReceiver(this.batteryChangeReceiver, battChangeFilter);
        Log.e("service", "broadcast receiver registered");


    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        googleClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if (null != googleClient && googleClient.isConnected()) {
            googleClient.disconnect();
        }
        Log.e("service", "okwear disconnected");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        String WEARABLE_DATA_PATH = "/wearable_data";

        // Create a DataMap object and send it to the data layer
        DataMap dataMap = new DataMap();
        dataMap.putLong("time", new Date().getTime());
        dataMap.putString("hole", "1");
        dataMap.putString("front", "250");
        dataMap.putString("middle", "260");
        dataMap.putString("back", "270");
        //Requires a new thread to avoid blocking the UI
        new SendToDataLayerThread(WEARABLE_DATA_PATH, dataMap).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        Log.e("Mobile","Failed to connect   Error::"+connectionResult.getErrorMessage());

    }



    private final BroadcastReceiver batteryChangeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            checkBatteryLevel(intent);
            Log.e("service","broadcast receiver called");
        }
    };


    private void checkBatteryLevel(Intent batteryChangeIntent) {
        // some calculations
        final int currLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
                BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
        final int maxLevel = batteryChangeIntent.getIntExtra(
                BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        final int percentage = (int) Math.round((currLevel * 100.0) / maxLevel);

        Log.d("MySerive", "current battery level: " + percentage);



        unregisterReceiver(batteryChangeReceiver);
        //return  percentage;
    }


    class SendToDataLayerThread extends Thread {
        String path;
        DataMap dataMap;

        // Constructor for sending data objects to the data layer
        SendToDataLayerThread(String p, DataMap data) {
            path = p;
            dataMap = data;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Construct a DataRequest and send over the data layer
            PutDataMapRequest putDMR = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
            putDMR.getDataMap().putAll(dataMap);
            PutDataRequest request = putDMR.asPutDataRequest();
            DataApi.DataItemResult result = Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleClient, request).await();
            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.v("myTag", "DataMap: " + dataMap + " sent successfully to data layer ");
            } else {
                // Log an error
                Log.v("myTag", "ERROR: failed to send DataMap to data layer");
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance...